# Evaluating $\sin(\pi/12) - \sin(5\pi/12)$

Tags: trigonometry

....I tried using the sum-to-product formulas but am missing a step where I have to convert to different values I guess?  Working through entire formula I end up with $\sqrt{3}$.  Answer is $-\sqrt{2}/2$.  If I convert to exact values using the difference formulas I arrive at the answer but not sure if that's correct.

[Discussion post with my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NakDB.png)

Comment: In your work it's $\sin(-4\pi/24)$ and not $\sin(-8\pi/12)$,also it should be $\sin(6\pi/24)$ and not $\sin(12\pi/12)$

Comment: That number is clearly negative. I have a suggestion: trust your guts more than your computation skills, always.

Comment: Wow.  *FACEPALM*

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses and letting me know I need a break.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$\sin(\frac{\pi}{4})$ is the mean of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{12})$ and $\sin(\frac{5\pi}{12})$ and we know $$\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},$$ and
$$\frac{\pi}{12}=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{6},$$
$$\frac{5\pi}{12}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{6}$$